# Создание DataFrame из Series в pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, анализ-данных

Как перевести результат группировки в новый датафрейм?

В результате исполнения кода:

```
import pandas as pd
import copy

ds = pd.read_csv('ds.csv', delimiter=',')
course_pivot = copy.deepcopy(ds.groupby(['course_title'])['student_id'].nunique())
```

получаю одномерный объект типа `Series`. При переводе `course_pivot` в `pd.DataFrame`, на выходе получается DataFrame с одним столбцом.

Как его сделать с двумя столбцами: `course_title` и `student_id`? Где `student_id` - это количество уникальных ID для каждого курса.

Вопрос элементарный, но я потратил пол дня, чтобы попытаться найти на него ответ.

[10 строк таблицы ds](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hSRpwOG8J8gg7G1RM5zdVFMRY0JkIeVV/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Вы сами указали, что хотите получить один столбец на выходе (после скобок метода groupby). Либо уберите ['student-id'], либо укажите списком нужные вам столбцы.

Comment: Вот так должно быть: 
`ds.groupby(['course_title', 'student_id'])`
Видите разницу?

Comment: @VektorValentine , спасибо, так действительно лучше. Только начинаю учить свой первый язык, иногда не догадываюсь пробовать что-то изменить.

Comment: @MaxU, выбрал ответ правильным. Это был мой первый вопрос, ещё не очень знаком с интерфейсом. Буду признателен за ответ и на второй вопрос. Я не из ИТ, вообще маркетолог, но решил расширить свои знания до тру аналитики.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
res = ds.groupby('course_title')['student_id'].nunique().reset_index(name="uniq_stud_id")
```

---

результат:

```
In [10]: res
Out[10]:
         course_title  uniq_stud_id
0  Веб-дизайн PRO 2.0             1
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что нужно. Через какое-то время понял, что в моём срезе course_title становится индексом.